# select specific items in json array using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have result.json that looks like this :

```
[
 {
  "id":"1",
  "label":"2017-03-30",
  "value":"1675000"
 },
 {
  "id":"2",
  "label":"2017-04-01",
  "value":"1440000"
 },
 {
  "id":"2",
  "label":"2017-04-02",
  "value":"830000"
 },
]
```

How can I get the specific items in json array . 
for example I wanted to make an output for each "value" if

```
id=2 and label=2017-04-01
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
console.log(arr.filter(item => {
    return item.id === `2` && item.label === `2017-04-01`;
}));
```

recommended Improvement:

```
var arr=[{
   "id":"1",
   "label":"2017-03-30",
   "value":"1675000"
 },
 {
   "id":"2",
   "label":"2017-04-01",
   "value":"1440000"
 },
 {
   "id":"2",
   "label":"2017-04-02",
   "value":"830000"
  },
];
console.log(...arr.filter(item => item.id === `2` && item.label === `2017-04-01`));
```

If you just want the values:

```
console.log(...arr.filter(item => item.id === `2` && item.label === `2017-04-01`).map(e=>e.value));
```

http://jsbin.com/fimulelebi/edit?console

Comment: That won't return `value` but entire object.

Comment: you could leave away the { return }

Comment: arr.filter(item => item.id === `2` && item.label === `2017-04-01`)[0]

Comment: @Alex ive just edited your code, if you think its better you can take it over, if not you can dump it...

Answer (score 1):

Use `forEach` method. Easy to use and navigate through items.

```js
var json = [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "label": "2017-03-30",
    "value": "1675000"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "label": "2017-04-01",
    "value": "1440000"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "label": "2017-04-02",
    "value": "830000"
  },
];

json.forEach(item => {
  if(item.id == "2" && item.label == "2017-04-01") {
    console.log(item.value);
  }
})
```

Comment: how if the json is on external files (result.json )?how do we call it on js?

Comment: Using Ajax. But that's question not related with what you asked here, so you should write new one. Before you do that, read about Ajax.